# Beautiful soup login returning 200 but not logged in

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following scraping is being implemented and login details are being posted. The page I want to check while logged in is:

https://www.liveauctioneers.com/search/?keyword=Thomas%20Gainsborough&sort=-relevance&status=archive

so as to see prices sold at. When I run, I get a 200 response (seemingly logging in) however I am not actually logged in.

```
URL = 'https://item-api-prod.liveauctioneers.com/auth/spalogin?c=20170802'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
    "name": "xxx@yahoo.com",
    "current-password": "xxx"
}

s = requests.session()
response = s.post(URL, data=payload, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: please provide a [mre].

Comment: You're not giving us much information, but I'd had a similar issue in unit tests where the login fails, redirects back to the login page, and successfully loads the form for the next login attempt. Try telling it not to follow redirects so you can see each step?

Comment: Why would you assume that a 200 response means you are logged in?  200 just means "the web server returned some content".

Comment: Websites usually expect you to visit the login page first, before actually submitting your login information.  Try adding `s.get(URL)` as the first thing in the session, before the post.

Answer (score -1):

The code you've shown is missing import statement for the requests module and the BeautifulSoup module. You need to import these modules before using them and make sure you have the requests library and beautifulsoup4 library installed in your system

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

if you have not install those library run this in terminal

```
pip install requests
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Of course I have those imports.... @dhruvi Joshi